# How do you get catkin command to work?

Tags: ros, catkin, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the other duplicate:

I'm watching ROS tutorials and keep getting stuck:

My system says:

"catkin: command not found"

Yet I've reloaded ROS a few times.  Even created a test user account in ubuntu 16.04

After I do half of all the Youtube ROS examples in Part 1 for example, I run any catkin command from anywhere in ubuntu 16.04 and I get msgs about "catkin: command not found"

Sheeesh

The good news is I never give up.  But WHY is catkin command not working?

---

Uninstalled and reloaded ROS Kinetic over and over again.  I get almost through ROS tutorial #1.

Then, tutorial says enter "catkin " something or another.

Result:

catkin: command not found.

Note: Using ROS Kinetic on ubuntu 16.04.3 LTC.

So I heard you need to create a non-admin user.

Did that.  Been there. Got the T shirt.

Even the new non-admin user can't get catkin commands to work.

Any help is appreciated as I never give up.

I solve this nasty, persistent problem or go on to more forums and ask it again.

And again..

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

- - 

Is catkin real or another weather balloon?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275640/how-do-you-get-catkin-command-to-work??/) by [ju78iklo9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32592/ju78iklo9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-11-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-12**:\

> I'm watching ROS tutorials and keep getting stuck:

and

> After I do half of all the Youtube ROS examples in Part 1 [..]

The 'official' ROS tutorials are text only, so if you're watching videos that would have to be community contributed content. **Always** link to that in questions. It's ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-12**:
.. impossible to help you otherwise.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-14**:
*Exactly* what command are you running? Where are you running it from (directory)? What tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> My system says:

> "catkin: command not found"

The official tutorials ([wiki/ROS/Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)) use `catkin_make`, so there the command would be:

```
catkin_make [...]
```

which would have been installed with a default ROS installation.

> After I do half of all the Youtube ROS examples in Part 1 for example, I run any catkin command from anywhere in ubuntu 16.04 and I get msgs about "catkin: command not found"

> [..]

> But WHY is catkin command not working?

As I wrote in my comment, we don't know *which* videos you are watching as you forgot to link us to them (*sheeeesh*). But `catkin` (like that, not `catkin_something_something`) is a script in `catkin_tools`, which on Ubuntu (and similar systems) must be explicitly installed with something like `sudo apt install python-catkin-tools` (but *after* you've added the ROS package repositories to your system configuration).

> Uninstalled and reloaded ROS Kinetic over and over again.

This is not Windows. Un/install is not going to solve the fact that you didn't install the package.

> I get almost through ROS tutorial #1. Then, tutorial says enter "catkin " something or another.

> Result:

> ```
> catkin: command not found.
> ```

"*"catkin " something or another*": I doubt it says "something or another".

> So I heard you need to create a non-admin user.
>
> Did that. Been there. Got the T shirt.
>
> Even the new non-admin user can't get catkin commands to work.

This makes no sense to me. At all.

> Is catkin real or another weather balloon?

..

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1